# $watch(Collection) doesn't catch object property changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this strings in a template:

```
<li class="list__item" ng-repeat="item in items">
  <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" ng-model="item.done">
  <label>{{ item.description }}</label>
  <button class="destroy" ng-click="remove(item)"></button>
</li>
```

And js code in my controller:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('items', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  cache.set($scope.items);
});
```

$scope.items are defined.

When I check one item, $watchCollection doesn't catch this change.
I read todo mvc source and didn't find my mistake.

Where is the mistake?
Thanks.

Comment: Where is the fiddle? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`watchCollection` watches for shallow changes in the `items` collection. It means it will fire only when elements are added/removed to the `items` collection. If you want the watch to fire when you change a property of an `item`, you have to use a `watch`.

From the docs:

> Shallow watches the properties of an object and fires whenever any of the properties change (for arrays, this implies watching the array items; for object maps, this implies watching the properties).

Comment: Thanks. I used just $watch('items', callback), but needed to use $watch('items', callback, true).